# Mule - Salesforce connector - Retrieve job failed results bulk v2 - not returning failed data

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am querying Salesforce Bulk api failed results in Mule. But it doesn't fetch the data. It jus shows the record id and error message. But if i check in workbench, it shows the id, error, datacolumns(a,b,c)
How to get those details..Is there any other way to get the bulk api v2 failed results in Mule

[image]

doing simple Transformation before logging

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

**Debug Log :**

[image]

On workbench, I get the actual data.

[image]

please share your thoughts why i don't see those data

Comment: Please add the bulk api request (in textual XML form) and the query from workbench to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/bulkapi/failures') 
global without sharing class RestGetBulkAPIResults 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static void getFailedRecords()
    {
       RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
       RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
       res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse httpRes = new HttpResponse();
        httpReq.setMethod('GET');
        httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        string path = '/services/data/v48.0/jobs/ingest/7502i000001fJG9AAM/failedResults/';
        httpReq.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+ path);
        httpRes = http.send(httpReq);
        
        string op = httpRes.getBody();
        string[] rowList = op.split('\n');
        
        string[] headers = rowList[0].split(',');
        integer columnsCount = headers.size();
        integer dataRowsCount = rowList.size();
        
        string fullFormattedData = '[';
        for(integer rowIndex =1; rowIndex < dataRowsCount; rowIndex++)
        {
      string[] rowData = rowList[rowIndex].split(','); 
            
            string rowJsonData ='{';
            for(integer columnIndex=0; columnIndex < columnsCount; columnIndex++)
            {
        rowJsonData += headers[columnIndex] + ':' + rowData[columnIndex] + ',';
            }
            rowJsonData = rowJsonData.removeEnd(',');
            rowJsonData += '}';
            fullFormattedData += rowJsonData;
        }
        fullFormattedData += ']';
        
        system.debug('resp' + httpRes.getBody());
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(fullFormattedData);
        res.statusCode = 200;
    }
}
```